# MongoDB | Listing the Zip Code/Postal Code for each City in New York

Tags: arrays, database, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am learning how to write MongoDB queries as part of my personal project. I think I am missing something small or big (I don't know), and hoping that someone could point to what is wrong with my MongoDB query. I am working on the popular zip code data set that is provided on MongoDB here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/aggregation-zip-code-data-set/

An example of a document in the zipcodes collection has the following form:

```
{
  "_id": "10280",
  "city": "NEW YORK",
  "state": "NY",
  "pop": 5574,
  "loc": [
    -74.016323,
    40.710537
  ]
}
```

**Goal:** I am trying to find the population of each city in the state of New York (NY) where the results list the postal codes that are included in **each** city. The output should look something like this:

```
{
    _id : "ELMIRA",
    population : <population of ELMIRA>,
    postal_codes : [
        <PostalCode1 in ELMIRE>,
        <PostalCode2 in ELMIRE>,
        <PostalCode3 in ELMIRA>
        ]
    },
    {
        _id : "WHITESVILLE",
        population : <population of WHITESVILLE>,
        postal_codes : [
            <PostalCode1 in WHITESVILLE>
        ]
    },
```

**My Code**: Here is what I have written so far

```
db.getCollection('codes').aggregate([
    { 
        $group: {
            _id: {city: "$city", state:"$state"},
            population: {$sum: "$pop"},
            postal_codes: {$addToSet: "$_id"}
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "_id.state":"NY"
        
        }
    
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id.city",
            population: {$last: "$population"},
            postal_codes: {$last: "$postal_codes"}
        }
    }       
])
```

**Problem** - The issue that I see with my code is that it only lists *one* of the zip codes for a city in New York that has multiple zip codes, as shown below. In the U.S., a city may overlap several postal codes. How can I fix my query to include *all* zip codes for each city in New York instead of one of them?

```
{ 
    "_id" : "OSSINING", 
    "population" : NumberInt(29926), 
    "postal_codes" : [
        "10562"
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : "COLD SPRING", 
    "population" : NumberInt(4904), 
    "postal_codes" : [
        "10516"
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : "NORTH WOODMERE", 
    "population" : NumberInt(19582), 
    "postal_codes" : [
        "11581"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LigN47XpZWZ) what you are looking for? The dataset is quite big so I can only sample a few documents out for testing.

Comment: The problem is that you are using $last in this line. postal_codes: {$last: "$postal_codes"}. $last is an array operator that only return the final value of the array. Change that $last to a $push, so every postal code is added and you shoul be fine.

Comment: @RubénVega, thank you for the comment. Let me change it to $push and test the changes. I will check if it resolves the issue.

Comment: @ray, yes, I am looking for something similar to what you have in your Mongo code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `$addToset` instead of `$last` to get all the `postal_codes`.

One side note: you can make your code a bit more performant by reducing the intermediate result set through pushing the `$match` by `state` to earlier stage.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "state": "NY"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$city",
      population: {
        $sum: "$pop"
      },
      postal_codes: {
        $addToSet: "$_id"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LigN47XpZWZ) for your reference.